# How do I use a value after calling Option::map?

Tags: rust

I am trying to:

1. Get an `Option<&str>` from somewhere, and build a `PathBuf` from it.
2. If `None`, print some message, and return.
3. If the path is not a directory, print a message saying the path is not a directory, and return.
4. If everything is good, continue the program.

```
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn it_works() {
    let path_str = Some("/tmp/abc");
    let path = path_str.map(|s| PathBuf::from(s));
    if !path.map_or(false, |p| p.is_dir()) {
        match path {
            Some(p) => println!("The folder {:?} is not a directory!", p),
            None => println!("The repository folder is not set!"),
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

The pattern matching in the above snippet doesn't work because the value has been moved in the `map_or` combinator:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value
 --> src/lib.rs:8:18
  |
5 |     let path = path_str.map(|s| PathBuf::from(s));
  |         ---- move occurs because `path` has type `std::option::Option<std::path::PathBuf>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
6 |     if !path.map_or(false, |p| p.is_dir()) {
  |         ---- value moved here
7 |         match path {
8 |             Some(p) => println!("The folder {:?} is not a directory!", p),
  |                  ^ value used here after move
```

I can do something like this, but it doesn't feel very "idiomatic" because of the `unwrap` and multiple `if` clauses:

```
let path_str = Some("/tmp/abc");
let path = path_str.map(|s| PathBuf::from(s));
if path.is_none() {
    println!("The repository folder is not set!");
    return;
}
let p = path.unwrap();
if !p.is_dir() {
    println!("The folder {:?} is not a directory!", p);
}
```

Could there be a better to solve this?

Comment: If you use `Path` instead of `PathBuf`, your code works more or less unchanged. (You just need ot use `Path::new` instead of `PathBuf::from`.)

Comment: Hmm... yes, `Path` works. But I am wondering why `Path` doesn't have the same ownership problem?

Comment: Because `Path` doesn't own the data in the first place – it borrows it from the original string. `Path::new()` actually returns a _reference_ to a Path, borrowing the orignal data. As a shared reference, `&Path` is `Copy`, so it can be consumed more than once. Creating a new `PathBuf`, on the other hand, creates a new owned copy of the original string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the closure in `.map(...)` (or any similar functions on an `Option`) doesn't need ownership of the value in the option (i.e. it only needs a reference to the value), you can always use [`option.as_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref) or [`option.as_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_mut) to turn an `&Option<T>` or `&mut Option<T>` into an `Option<&T>` or `Option<&mut T>`. Then calling `.map()` will not take ownership because references are copyable, so it's just copied into the provided closure.

With this in mind, your code would be modified to be this:

```
fn it_works() {
    let path_str = Some("/tmp/abc");
    let path = path_str.map(|s| PathBuf::from(s));
    if !path.as_ref().map_or(false, |p| p.is_dir()) {
        //  ^^^^^^^^^ using .as_ref() here
        //                          ^^^ now p is a '&PathBuf' instead of 'PathBuf'

        match path {
        //    ^^^^ we didn't take ownership so compiler doesn't complain here

            Some(p) => println!("The folder {:?} is not a directory!", p),
            None => println!("The repository folder is not set!"),
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`PathBuf` implements `FromStr` trait, so you can use it, in combination with powerful pattern matching.

```rust
fn it_works() {
    use std::path::*;
    use std::str::FromStr;

    let path_str: Option<&str> = Some("/tmp/abc");
    match path_str.map(PathBuf::from_str) {
        Some(Ok(p)) => if !p.is_dir() {},
        Some(Err(e)) => {}
        None => {}
    };
}
```